# checking version in shell script using regex

Tags: regex, shell

Could anybody suggest a reg ex for checking versions 
What if I like to check any update version in 1.0.0 release may be `1.0.0-1` or `1.0.0-2` or `1.0.0-3` and I just need to check for what update version is it `-1 or -2 or -3` `1.0.0-1` or `1.0.0-2` or `1.0.0-3` what regex can I use ? 
tried

```
sed -ne s/1.0.0\-[0-9]\1/p
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?:

```
$ echo "1.0.0-1" | sed -ne 's/1.0.0\(\-[0-9]\)/\1/p'
-1
```

The regex to get the update number for any version would be:

```
$ echo "1.0.0-1" | sed -ne 's/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\(\-[0-9]\)/\1/p'
-1
```

The trick is to capture the output you want between `\(` and `\)` grouping parentheses and the use `\1` to output the pattern in the replace part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This will leave only the update version number:

```
echo "1.0.0-1" | sed -e 's/^[1-9][0-9.]*-//'
```

And this will leave the leading '-' on it:

```
echo "1.0.0-1" | sed -e 's/^[1-9][0-9.]*//'
```

The p command isn't needed in the above so I left it, and the -n option off, but you can restore them if this part of some more elaborate sed script.

Edit: OP apparently just wants to know if the version contains an update. Here are a couple of ways in classic bourne shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
version='1.0.0-1'
case "$version" in
    *-[1-9]*)  # Not a regex, this is a (file) "pattern"
        # Update triggered code here
        ;;
esac

# Or:
if echo "$version" | grep '-[1-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null ; then
    # Update triggered code here
fi
```

There are other ways to do it in other shells/environments of course.

Comment: Thanks ! but I was only looking for checking update in script

Comment: Thanks ! But I was only looking for regex to check something like this
if ("1.0.0-any version")
"run this command "
else don't run
e.g
$ver = 1.0.0-2
if [ -z "$(echo $ver | awk '/7.0.0-*/')" ];
then `date`  #<or any command>

Comment: Sorry, it looked like you were trying to do a substitution (that's what the 's' command in sed does) to isolate the update portion of the version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a regular expression here; just split the string on the correct character:

```
version=1.0.0-2
major=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f1 )
minor=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f1 )
patchlvl=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d - -f1 )
build=$(echo $version | cut -d - -f2)
```